# What will be scope of variable if I don't define it as var or let?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am quite new to JS, Pardon me if this is not a valid question.

What will be scope/type (var/let) of variable if I don't define it as var or let?

Say,

```
function f1(){
 a="Sample"
 console.log("F1",a);
}

function f2(){
 console.log("F2",a);
}
f2();
```

It Outputs: `F2 Sample`

I understand function and block level scope of let and var but here how `a` is printing, thats confusing.

Answer (score 0):

It will attach itself to the global object, and will become a global variable.

```
function f1(){
    a="Sample"
}
console.log(a) // Uncaught ReferenceError because there is no a variable in global scope till now.
f1()
console.log(a) // "Sample"
```

Edit: After suggestion by @Quentin

Below statement will just declare `testVar` in global scope if used without 'use-strict'

```
testVar = 17
```

but below will throw ReferenceError

```
'use-strict'
testVar = 17
```

> **Conclusion:**
>   Strict mode makes it impossible to accidentally create global
>   variables. In normal JavaScript mistyping a variable in an assignment
>   creates a new property on the global object and continues to "work" .
>   Assignments, which would accidentally create global variables, instead
>   throw an error in strict mode

Comment: Maybe. It might also throw an exception.

Comment: Exception is thrown when you try to access a vaiable which is not yet defined. So after function execution since `a` was not defined inside function scope it is hoisted to the global object

Comment: You should read up on strict mode. Attempting to implicitly declare a global will throw an exception when it is enabled (which it should be as it catches all sort of bad practices that can lead to logic errors)

Comment: In 'strict-mode' you will get the error, but it was not there in the question.

Comment: So? A complete answer would still mention it.